# Laravel añadir un atributo dinámico a un modelo

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-6, laravel-7

tengo un modelo donde recupero los atributos de la BD pero hay uno que lo quiero hacer de forma dinámica cogiendo el atributo "image" del modelo y concatenando un string, para ello tengo esto en el modelo.

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Product extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name','image','price','tax','description','active'];

    protected $appends = ['image_route'];

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageRoute()
{
    return  storage_path('product_images/'.$this->attributes['image']);
}
}
```

Y luego desde el controlador intento recuperarlo de esta forma

```
public function show($id)
{

    $product = Product::find($id);

    if (null === $product) {
        return response()->json(['error' => Controller::HTTP_STATUS_CODE_404],404);
    }

    return response()->json($product,200);
}
```

El error que recibo es este

```
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Models\Product::getImageRouteAttribute() in file
C:\Apache24\htdocs\api-test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para definir un [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) se debe seguir el siguiente formato:

```
get{Attribute}Attribute
```

Por lo que tu método:

```
getImageRoute
```

En realidad debería llamarse:

```
getImageRouteAttribute
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ví mi fallo. 1000 gracias otra vez.